# Git lfs removed code from every single file - Kotlin

Tags: android, git, kotlin, git-lfs

I was using git lfs for some large files as I had committed prior to use it, so I had to use `git lfs migrate import` as provided [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn?utm_source=gitlfs_site&utm_medium=doc_man_migrate_link&utm_campaign=gitlfs#examples) which re-wrote the commits and then I was able to push it on the server. But, in turn, it has changed whole project's every .kt, .xml file to these 3 lines:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:e1bc1da7265eea2b374ddf30546ddabfa
size 21093
```

Opening any file over Github is not working as well but downloading a file and opening it works which means I still have a backup plus the ZIP backup I always create. How to clear/rollback this mess because I've a huge project?.

Terminal Log:

```
C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\X>git lfs migrate import
migrate: override changes in your working copy? [Y/n] y
migrate: changes in your working copy will be overridden ...
migrate: Fetching remote refs: ..., done.
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done.
migrate: Rewriting commits: 100% (2/2), done.
  master        f42b3a9d9874f2da0922 -> 7a1881a54a114be8474
migrate: Updating refs: ..., done.
migrate: checkout: ..., done.

C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\X>git lfs migrate info
migrate: Fetching remote refs: ..., done.
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done.
migrate: Examining commits: 100% (2/2), done.
*.xml   109 KB  845/845 files(s)        100%
*.kt    80 KB   621/621 files(s)        100%
*.png   22 KB   173/173 files(s)        100%
*.ttf   1.6 KB    12/12 files(s)        100%
*.apk   1.2 KB      9/9 files(s)        100%

C:\Users\X\Documents\Projects\X>git push -u origin master
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1695/1695), 1.4 GB | 3.7 MB/s, done.
Enumerating objects: 3332, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3332/3332), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1823/1823), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1852/1852), 256.98 KiB | 735.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1852 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7), completed with 3 local objects.
To https://github.com/X/X.git
   6ee589d..7a1881a  master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

Also, now I can't see Git in Android Studio, no options even in the above VCS menu. I checked the whole project, it has removed code from every single file, even from gradle files, .idea configurations files, text files etc.

Comment: Have you run `git lfs install` in your repository?  If not, does doing that and then checking out the branch you want fix the problem?

Comment: Git-LFS is not Git (it *uses* Git but sits in front of it), but that is in fact what it's supposed to do. Those three-line files are what get stored in Git by Git-LFS. They are "pointer files": the stuff in them enables Git-LFS to go retrieve the actual files. That's why you must now use Git-LFS for everything.

Comment: You can either continue to use Git-LFS (make sure you use that `git lfs install` thing—note that it has to be done in *each clone* ), or go back to a repository from the time before you did the import.

Comment: @torek The only way I can see the code in files by going to the website, opening a file, clicking on `view raw`, downloading it and then opening it with any viewer.

Comment: A repository from before `git lfs migrate` will still have the original commits, which hold the original files. A repository from afterward has all-new commits; the new commits have the pointer files installed in place of any migrated file.

Comment: @torek Hi, I read their help docs and found one command `git lfs checkout` described as "Populate working copy with real content from Git LFS files.". I ran it and it brought back the content. But, can I remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it". Remove what? You have some old repositories (full copies of *every* commit containing *every* file) that are not Git-LFS-ized, and some new repositories (full copies of *every* pointer-file pointing to externalized files), and some externalized files. That's what you have. Pick some set of these to use.

Comment: @torek By "it", I meant git lfs, no worries, I've changed the `.gitattributes` on which this `git lfs` works so I hope it won't be problematic again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue which was new for me. It might help others.

So, What I wanted to do was to support large files, I used `git lfs` but as I had already committed the code, I had to use `git lfs migrate import` which edits already committed changes and add the "supposedly" big files to its repository capable to store large files.

But, this command added all the files and provided a pointer as mentioned in the comments by Torek.

I read their help docs and to resolve the issue, first I ran a command `git lfs checkout` which brings back the original content of the files from the repo to local files and then I removed all type of files added to `.gitattributes` except few for which I used `git lfs` on the first place. `git lfs` works with `.gitattributes`.

Then, I just did a new commit and push and everything works fine now. Hell of a journey at midnight, blew my sleep.